# `APPEND` variable does not update kernel command line

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, bitbake

The manual https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.5/kernel-dev/kernel-dev.html at section C.1.6 states that:

> The Linux kernel command line is typically specified in the machine
> config using the APPEND variable.

in my bbappend of my embedded linux recipe I added:

```
APPEND_append = " isolcpus=2"
```

I forced a rebuild of `virtual/kernel` and the image recipe but find `/sys/devices/system/cpu/isolated` to be empty.

Do I **have** to set this variable in the machine config? If yes, why is it stated that this is 'typically' done there?

What else could have gone wrong?

EDIT: I put `APPEND += "isolcpus=2"` into my `local.conf`. Unfortunately, that line still doesn't make it into my `/proc/cmdline` of my target image.

Comment: This is **not** what documentation says. The example is: `APPEND += "isolcpus=2"`

Comment: @OleksandrKravchuk thanks for pointing that detail out. I put `APPEND += "isolcpus=2"` into my `local.conf`. Unfortunately, that line still doesn't make it into my `/proc/cmdline`. Do you have another hint that might help me move forward?

Comment: Hm... It might be overwritten somewhere? Grep source code and see where else it's modiefied.